# Opening modal on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, modal-dialog

I am using a animatedModal.js to display full screen modal on my page.
It works properly and is triggered by clicking on a button.

But, instead of that, i would need it to open automatically once the user enters the site, aka, it needs to be opened before the main page content.

This is the markup:

```
<!-- MODAL STARTS -->
<a id="demo01" href="#animatedModal">DEMO01</a>
    <div id="animatedModal">
        <div class="close-animatedModal"> 
            CLOSE MODAL
        </div>
        <div class="modal-content">
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- PAGE CONTENT -->
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
```

And it is triggered by

```
$("#demo01").animatedModal();
```

Fiddle can be found at https://jsfiddle.net/5zLe3npu/

What would be the best solution to display it first, before the content?
I am a JS newbie so sorry for potentially stupid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the .on method to specify what to do on-click of the close button, such as showing the content.  And to hide the content initially you could just use style='display:none;' on a  containing the content.

HTML -

```
<!-- MODAL STARTS -->
<div id="animatedModal">
    <div class="close-animatedModal"> 
        CLOSE MODAL
    </div>
    <div class="modal-content">
    </div>
</div>

<!-- PAGE CONTENT -->
<div id='container' style='display:none;'>

    <a id="demo01" href="#animatedModal">DEMO01</a>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>

</div>
```

JQuery -

```
$("#demo01").animatedModal(); //initialize animatedModal
$("#demo01").click(); //triggers opening of Modal.
$(".close-animatedModal").on( "click", function() {
    $("#container").show();
});
```

Please see JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/w1gw64aj/

If this answers your question, please mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: Hey Wise! This is exactly what i am looking for but i couldnt make it work properly on my end (again, i really am a jquery newbie), is there a chance you could help me? https://jsfiddle.net/5zLe3npu/2/
Ofcourse, marking it as accepted, thanks a bunch!

Comment: According to documentation http://learn.jquery.com/events/triggering-event-handlers/#trigger-vs-triggerhandler- Triggering events are not recommend. Best approach is wrap the code that opens the dialog into a function and use it to assign as an event and for execute directly.

Comment: No problem @TorcaVino.  I updated your JSFiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/5zLe3npu/3/

Answer (score 2):

Use `trigger()` [API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Try this

```
$("document").ready(function() {

        $("#demo01").animatedModal();
        $("#demo01").trigger('click');

});
```

**[Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/5zLe3npu/1/)**

Comment: it does open automatically, but the homepage is still visible during load.
the idea is that the modal loads first and then homepage is revealed once user closes the modal.
is there a chance to delay opening the main content div for 2-3 seconds or something like that?