# how to have this spcific animatedModal.js load up on document.ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog

Ok, so, I'm attempting to use this modal plugin: http://joaopereirawd.github.io/animatedModal.js/

But I would like to have it come on page's appearance instead of clicking on it.

So, I've varied on the page's direction with this code instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#demo01").animatedModal();
        });
</script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
            $("#demo01").animatedModal();
        });
</script>
```

But neither works. What am I missing here? How do I get this to work?

Here is the full html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Animated Modal</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.4.0/animate.min.css">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="animatedModal.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
            $("#demo01").animatedModal();
        });
</script>
<style type="text/css">

</style>
</head>

<body>
    <!--Call your modal-->
    <div id="demo01" href="#animatedModal">

    <!--DEMO01-->
    <div id="animatedModal">
        <!--THIS IS IMPORTANT! to close the modal, the class name has to match the name given on the ID  class="close-animatedModal" -->
        <div class="close-animatedModal"> 
            <img src="images.jpg">
        </div>

        <div class="modal-content">
         <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vitae pulvinar velit. Proin consequat luctus diam, ac posuere sapien. Vivamus purus odio, suscipit vitae libero ut, sollicitudin euismod sem. Sed eu efficitur diam. Nunc purus lacus, faucibus commodo convallis eget, congue at quam. Sed auctor mattis dui, id consectetur augue blandit nec. Proin sit amet libero a dolor cursus placerat. In quis porta augue. Etiam sagittis sit amet lorem a laoreet.</p>

        </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [info on animatedModal.js page](https://joaopereirawd.github.io/animatedModal.js/), `animatedModal()` is used not for displaying the modal, but merely to initialize it. It seems that this library hasn't got any method for showing the modal programatically, so you need to trigger a `click` event on the specific `div`. I'm assuming however, that you don't want any `div` to be visible, so you need to `display: hidden` it. A bit ugly solution, but it might work.

Below is an excerpt from [Opening modal on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32823247/opening-modal-on-page-load):

```
$("#demo01").animatedModal(); //initialize animatedModal
$("#demo01").click(); //triggers opening of Modal.
```

There is a pull request to add this feature, but it's not in release version yet:
https://github.com/joaopereirawd/animatedModal.js/pull/15